# mysql select default values from table if user specific ones aren't found

Tags: mysql, select, default

I've got a table of statuses.

```
ID         UserID   StatusID   Description
1          0        0          ready
2          0        1          on hold
3          0        2          cancelled
4          3        1          waiting
5          3        2          deleted
6          3        4          waiting on supplier
7          4        5          postponed
```

etc...

UserID 0 holds my default descriptions. I want to pull out all the status text for a user ***and*** the defaults if there are no user values with the same status ID.
eg user ID 3 should return

```
ID         UserID   StatusID   Description
    1          0        0          ready
    4          3        1          waiting
    5          3        2          deleted
    6          3        4          waiting on supplier
```

eg user ID 4 should return

```
ID         UserID   StatusID   Description
1          0        0          ready
2          0        1          on hold
3          0        2          cancelled
7          4        5          postponed
```

User ID 7 should return

```
ID         UserID   StatusID   Description
1          0        0          ready
2          0        1          on hold
3          0        2          cancelled
```

so far I have this:

```
select description.* from status_description description 
join (
    select max(id) as maxid from (
    select * from status_description default where default.user_id = 0
    union
    select * from status_description userstatus where ectfsa.user_id = 67
    ) as subset
    group by subset.ID
) as newest_desc on newest_desc.maxid = description.id
order by StatusID asc;
```

Where I union both the users statuses and the default statuses and then join the max ID per statusID back with the original table to get the user and defaults.

This works fine until someone adds a new USERID0 status with a higher ID.  Eg we decide that all users should now have an option of "postponed"  and we add a line

```
ID         UserID   StatusID   Description
8          0        5          next week
```

which should be the same "status" as "postponed" but worded differently for all users to what UserID 4 has.

If there a more graceful way of doing this without using Max and just selecting defaults and adding user statuses overwriting defaults where they already exist?

I need to keep this within mysql (ie not php) as its going to be a join to another query to pull out user specific descriptions for another report.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a solution :

```
select * from (
    select StatusID,Description from status_description default where default.user_id = 0
    union
    select StatusID,Description from status_description userstatus where ectfsa.user_id = 67
    ) as StatusID;
```

I don't need the UserID in the result or the ID.  By  removing these from the union by replacing the * with field names the union automatically removes duplicates, or at least appears to...